# Regular Expressions and Results

Tags: javascript, python, expression

I was wondering what words out of (bad, bread, bed, brad, breed, bead, bard) can be returned from the regular expression -- br?[ea]+d -- ???

I'm not really sure what else to try.

Thankyou for any help :)

Comment: Did you try it? What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can test this on https://regex101.com/ or any other similar website.

For the following regex:

> br?[ea]+d

It matched all words except

> bard

Comment: No problem, if this helped you, upvoting and marking as the correct answer could potentially help the community if someone else has a regex question.

Comment: Is there any chance that you would be able to tell me what words from (tough, touch, taught, timeout, tooth, teeth, tenth, trench, twentieth, or twelfth) can be returned from t[aeiou]+[a-z]*t -- the last part has confused me

Comment: Just go to the website I linked and put your regex and words in there, it will show the matches as groups

Comment: @ChalyseFoster, this isn't a place where we do your homework for you. Try to learn from this answer and apply what you've learned.

Answer (score 0):

All of these are acceptable

['bad', 'bread', 'bed', 'brad', 'breed', 'bead']

except bard

Explanation:-

'b' is compulsory.After that

'r' is optional. After that

[ea] stands for matching one alphabet from {e,a}

so [ea]+ stands for matching continuous sub string consisting of either of 'a' or 'e'

and finally  'd' is compulsory.

Therefore you can check only 'bard' doesn't satisfy above criteria because of r followed by a which doesn't match the given regex

Comment: Thankyou that makes more sense now

Comment: I've tried to apply what you've written to another one, t[aeiou]+[a-z]*t but I am confused how it could equal any of (tough, touch, taught, timeout, tooth, teeth, tenth, trench, twentieth, or twelfth) with the [a-z]*t part of it

Comment: `[a-z]*` means any letter from a to z, any amount of times, even 0 times making it optional. `t` is compulsory.

Comment: first of all 't' at end is compulsory and 
* refers to matching preceding group ie any of [a-z] 0 or more times

so
[a-z]* matches all the string that contains only lowercase alphabet whatever be the length e.g. 
"anythingcontainingatoz" ,everything"

but not "12fsdf..sd" since it contains non alpha characters which isn't allowed